Power BI current week information only on visual - does not change due to slicers
I am trying to create a measure that feeds the visual, however I cannot get it to just look at current week or last week without being affected by slicers.
Here is the code so far:
VAR CurrentWeek = SELECTEDVALUE(Fiscal[Week])
    VAR CurrentYear = SELECTEDVALUE(Fiscal[Fiscal Year])
       VAR MaxWeekNumber = CALCULATE(MAX(Fiscal[Week]), ALL(Fiscal))

RETURN
    FILTER(ALL(Fiscal),
        IF(CurrentWeek = 1,
            Fiscal[Week] = MaxWeekNumber && Fiscal[Fiscal Year] = CurrentYear)))

Another try is :
FILTER(ALL(Fiscal),
    Fiscal[Week] = SELECTEDVALUE(Fiscal[Week]) - 1 &&
        Fiscal[Fiscal Year] = SELECTEDVALUE(Fiscal[Fiscal Year])))

The first one does not return a number, and the second one is affected by the filters.

Can you please provide some example data and expected output? Also, both your measures do not return a single value. What are you attempting to calculate and what columns are being used as slicers?
